# Retrieve data from firebase and display it in extendable recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve user appointment and display it with user selected time in recyclerview  based on today date after I check if key node is exist but
I have issue that when I retrieve data from firebase it's only display duplicated items of the last value that I retrieve from firebase  with all list of time of all user because adapter only triggers once..any help please

here is json
[image]
here is code

```
    private void RetriveAllAppointment(ArrayList<String> id_list) {
            DatabaseReference mrefDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Appointments").child("Active");
            mrefDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        MyBooking booking = new MyBooking();
                        times_list = new ArrayList<>();
                        clearall();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                          key = snapshot.getKey();
                          //loop over ids
                            for (int i = 0; i < id_list.size(); i++) {
                                if (id_list.get(i).equals(key)) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot Activesnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        String date = Activesnapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString();
                                        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
                                        LocalDate fromLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);
                                        if (fromLocalDate.equals(LocalDate.now())) {
                                            booking.setDate(Activesnapshot.child("Date").getValue().toString());
                                            booking.setVenueName(Activesnapshot.child("venueName").getValue().toString());
                                            booking.setUserbookedName(Activesnapshot.child("userbookedName").getValue().toString());
                                            booking_list.add(booking);
                                            DataSnapshot timesSnapshot = Activesnapshot.child("times");
                                            for (DataSnapshot timesnapshot : timesSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                time = timesnapshot.getValue().toString();
                                                times_list.add(time);
                                                booking.setTimesList(times_list);
                                                //  todayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                            }
    
                                        }
 
                                       } }
                                   
  todayAdapter = new TodayReservationAdapter(booking_list, context);
TodayReservation_recyclerview.setAdapter(todayAdapter);
 todayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }
                            } }
    
    
    
                    }else{
                        //display empty view
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and show us the exact data you want to get.

Comment: I edit my question and add firebase json @AlexMamo

Comment: How does `.getReference("Appointments").child("Active")` relate to the JSON that you showed?

Comment: the json here is the child of Active node ,,it's contain multiple ids that I have to compaer between them and my list of ids then if it's match get the values inside that nodes @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your screenshot, there are two dynamic levels under the root: `-MqV...fZ` and then the children under that, starting with `-MrN-wGw".

That means that the `DataSnapshot` you get from the data will contain two levels of nested snapshots with dynamic keys too, and thus you need two nested loops over `snapshot.getChildren()`.

So something like this should be closer:

```
for (DataSnapshot childsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
  Log.i("database", "Key of first level child: "+childsnapshot.getKey());
  for (DataSnapshot Activesnapshot : childsnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Log.i("database", "Key of second level child: "+Activesnapshot.getKey());
    String date = Activesnapshot.child("Date").getValue(String.class);
    ...
```

Comment: I'm already add two nested loops over the snap shot the first one to get key and second one to get values of snapshot if match date but still not able to get value in second value  properly @FrankvanPuffelen